# Why Trigger ready Flow can't have a Screen element?

Tags: visual-workflow

I am new to salesforce.I am getting this warning while crating a flow. Trigger ready Flow can't have a Screen element. Remove this element If you want it to be trigger-ready flow. This is the my flow [image: Diagram of my flow]

This is the warning I am getting.
[image: Warning Snapshot]

Why I am getting this warning ? I had created another flow and ended those with screen element but it didn't show any warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger ready flows are directly invoked through workflows and hence they dont need any screen.The input parameters will be through workflow .

If you need screen you will need to use normal flows.

More on the Trigger Ready Flows

> Flow trigger workflow actions and trigger-ready flows are currently available through a pilot program. For information on enabling this feature in your organization, contact salesforce.com.

Here is the info on how to use trigger ready flows

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/he-il/spring14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_process_flow_action.htm

> A trigger-ready flow is a flow that can be launched from a flow trigger workflow action. Because trigger-ready flows must be able to run in bulk and without user interaction, they can’t contain Step, Screen, or Apex Plug-in elements in any flow version.

Comment: can you please tell me how flows are invoked through workflows ?

Comment: I have provided explanation for the same .Hope that helps